# Загрузка компонента Angular 7

Tags: typescript, angular7

Есть 5 проектов у которых есть свои конфигурации. При запуске одного проекта иницилизируется один проект и его конфигурации. Когда перехожу на следующий проект меняется только url, но компонент не иницилизируется а просто выводит теже данные что и для первого проекта. Если я хожу по конфигам то данные подгружаются. Но если перехожу на след проект нужно опять же жать на ссылки конфигураций что бы данные изменились. Как заставить компонент перезагрузить консктруктор и подгрузить другие конфигурации по смене проекта?

Comment: Кэширование правильно настрой.

Comment: Кэширование http запросов?

Comment: Ответов на них.

Comment: Хм.. Но у меня не запросы кэшируются получается а компонент. Т.к компонент после перехода на другой проект не иницилизируется а просто переключает страницу. А как кэшировать компоненты:?

Comment: Кто-то из нас чего-то не понимает...

Comment: Так и есть. Где то заблудился

Comment: У меня просто проекты вытягиваются динамически. У них есть конфигурации. Так вот по переходу по ним такие косяки

Comment: По описанию похоже на кэширование. Больше я ничего не понял. Жди кого-нибудь, кто поймёт точнее, либо просто в курсе, о чём ты говоришь. Либо сделай вопрос более подробным и более понятным.